# Itext 7 Line Feed

Tags: itext7

Been trying to add a paragraph linefeed in Itext7. I've read where NEW TEXT("\n") will do it but it's not working.

```
   Dim P As Paragraph = New Paragraph()

    With P
        .SetTextAlignment(TextAlignment.LEFT)
        .SetFontSize(10)
        .Add(New Text("My Company LLC. "))
        .Add(New Text("\n"))
        .Add(New Text("Company Address"))
    End With
```

I'm looking for output of

My Company LLC.
Company Address

I'm getting  "My Company LLC. \nCompany Address"
This is driviing mew nuts. WOuld the cure be to use SetFixedPosition?

Thanks

-dan

Answer (score 0):

Still havent found a linefeed option  but this works for me.

```
   Dim L1 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("My Company. ")).SetFixedPosition(50, 800, 600)
   Dim L2 As Paragraph = New Paragraph(New Text("My Address  ")).SetFixedPosition(50, 790, 600)
```

Then I just added them to the document and whola  it works.

Answer (score 0):

Found a post by: Metro Smurf.

Add(Environment.NewLine)   works great (I'm Using itext7)

```
 Dim p2 = New Paragraph()
    p2.Add("Dan Tester")
    p2.Add(Environment.NewLine)
    p2.Add("123 Main St. Suite 3")
    p2.Add(Environment.NewLine)
    p2.Add("Midlife USA, XXXXX")


    p2.SetPaddingBottom(50)
    document.Add(p2)
```

Then add the new paragraph (even in a cell) and all is well.